# Trigger Lambda function when creating new Cognito Identity

Tags: amazon-cognito

I want to use Cognito Federated Identities with multiple Authentication Providers, and I want to manage my own user database so I have a simple immutable unique user id for other areas of the application.

What would be the correct way to trigger a lambda function that inserts newly authenticated users into my user database?

If I was only using Cognito User Pools I could use the offered triggers, and would create a mapping of the User Pool's unique "sub" id to my applications user id, but if I use other Authentication Provider's (Facebook etc..) through Federated Identities there are no triggers offered.

I cannot see any triggers within Federated Identities.

I understand User Pools can now do federation within User Pools, meaning a Facebook sign up there would create a User Pool identity which would have a "sub" id I could use, but I feel the federation in User Pool's is not as mature and strong as in Federated Identities, there are also less Providers to choose from.

Secondary question: Is there a best standard for mapping Authentication Providers ids to my application user id? I understand sub is an immutable unique id for User Pools, but Federated Identitie's "Identity ID" can merge and thus change so I guess best practive would be to use each Authentication Provider's unique id?